# Add automatic animation to hover effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am interested in a carousel animation. so far it reacts to hover. So when I go to the second or third element, these areas enlarge and more information is shown. the areas should also open up one after the other or react as if you were driving across the other two areas. i was looking for slides and carousel animation but i don't know exactly what to look for.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".bloc").hover(function () {
     $(this).toggleClass("active"); //Toggle the active class to the area is hovered
     $('.first').toggleClass("active"); //Toggle the active class to the area is hovered
   });
 });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:200,300,400,500,600,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700');
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  columns: 3;
  width: calc(25% - 22px);
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  transition: .5s all ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li .bloc {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul li .content {
  opacity: 0;
  left: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 6px solid #FFF;
  padding-left: 20px;
  transition: .2s all;
  user-select: none;
}
ul li .content H2 {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li .content H3 {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0;
}
.active .content {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 2s all;
  transition-delay: .5s;
}
ul li .bloc::before {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: opacity 1s;
}
.active {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(50% - 22px);
  transition: .5s all ease-in-out;
}
.active::before {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: opacity 1s;
}
.first {
  background: red;
}
.second {
  background: red;
}
.third {
  float: right;
  background: red;
}
@keyframes opacity {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="bloc first active">
      <div class="content">
        <H2>First title</H2>
        <H3>It's a first subtitle</H3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="bloc second">
      <div class="content">
        <H2>Second title</H2>
        <H3>Subtitle</H3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="bloc third">
      <div class="content">
        <H2>Third title</H2>
        <H3>Last subtitle</H3>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

to describe it better, I added a gif animation of how the elements should behave.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is.  The code in the snippet appears to be animating just fine.  What is it that is missing or incorrect?

Comment: the areas should change automatically as shown in the gif. so in addition to the hover. i changed the title

Comment: I'm going to restate my understanding of your requirements to verify that I have them correct-- you want to retain the expansion on hover, but also want it to happen automatically if not hovering, as seen in the gif, correct?  And I presume a user action like a hover will take precedence and cause the automatic expansions to stop until the user is no longer hovering?

Comment: that's exactly how it is meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` to create a continuous animation and temporarily stop that interval when the user hovers over one of the slides.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const animation = () => {
    const activeCarouselElement = $('.bloc.active');
    activeCarouselElement.removeClass('active');

    const nextCarouselElement = activeCarouselElement.next().length ? activeCarouselElement.next() : activeCarouselElement.siblings()[0];
    $(nextCarouselElement).addClass('active');
  };
  
  let animationInterval = setInterval(animation, 3500);

  $(".bloc").hover(function() {
    $('.bloc.active').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    clearInterval(animationInterval);
  });
   
  $(".bloc").mouseleave(function() {
      animationInterval = setInterval(animation, 3500);
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:200,300,400,500,600,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700');
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  columns: 3;
  width: calc(25% - 22px);
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  transition: .5s all ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul li .bloc {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul li .content {
  opacity: 0;
  left: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 6px solid #FFF;
  padding-left: 20px;
  transition: .2s all;
  user-select: none;
}

ul li .content H2 {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li .content H3 {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0;
}

.active .content {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 2s all;
  transition-delay: .5s;
}

ul li .bloc::before {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: opacity 1s;
}

.active {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(50% - 22px);
  transition: .5s all ease-in-out;
}

.active::before {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: opacity 1s;
}

.first {
  background: red;
}

.second {
  background: red;
}

.third {
  float: right;
  background: red;
}

@keyframes opacity {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="bloc first active">
      <div class="content">
        <H2>First title</H2>
        <H3>It's a first subtitle</H3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="bloc second">
      <div class="content">
        <H2>Second title</H2>
        <H3>Subtitle</H3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="bloc third">
      <div class="content">
        <H2>Third title</H2>
        <H3>Last subtitle</H3>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```